# Is there a way to use wrapbootstrap themes with Angular2?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, angular

We are trying to make a decision on a CSS framework.

We found https://wrapbootstrap.com/themes/admin and are wondering if there is a way to make these css themes work with Angular2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is any problem if you are going to use any CSS theme/framework with angular2.even i have used same ADMIN LTE dashboard for my project and code is running smoothly, but yes the problem may arise at the time of initialization of some plugin which use JQuery. so be alert from those type of code.

if you are using Admin theme you can initialize your JQuery code in the `ngOnInit` life cycle hook of angular2.

also there are verity of css themes available those are easly compatible with angular2 like

- BootFlat (http://bootflat.github.io/documentation.html)
- Materialize CSS (http://materializecss.com/)

Answer (score 0):

These css themes should work with angular 2 like everything else.
Just remember they use jQuery so it won't be very comfortable nor effective mixing all together.